# How to preserve class type when calling intermediate generic method

Tags: java, class, generics, types

**I have a method which calls a generic method, which is instantiated for some types for special behaviours:**

```
public static void generic_direct(String s)
{
System.out.println("YOU SUBMIT STRING: premium class");
}

public static <T>  void generic_direct(T t)
{
System.out.println("YOU SUBMIT GENERIC: second class");
}


System.out.println("TEST STRING ?");
generic_direct("what ?");
System.out.println("TEST INTEGER ?");
generic_direct(12345);
```

gives desired behaviour:

```
TEST STRING ?
YOU SUBMIT STRING: premium class
TEST INTEGER ?
YOU SUBMIT GENERIC: second class
```

**but when it is called via another generic method, you lose class types**

```
public static <T>  void generic_indirect(T t)
{
generic_direct(t);
}

System.out.println("TEST STRING ?");
generic_indirect("what ?");
System.out.println("TEST INTEGER ?");
generic_indirect(12345);
```

give this:

```
TEST STRING ?
YOU SUBMIT GENERIC: second class
TEST INTEGER ?
YOU SUBMIT GENERIC: second class
```

**So is it possible, and how to preserve the class type, when intermediate generic methods are used, without having to instantiate every intermediate method with possible types ?**

Answer (score 1):

By using the **generic_indirect(T)** method you lose type safety, because the Java compiler will replace the generic type **T** with Object. As far as I know, there is no workaround for this. You can find more about type erasure [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

After compilation your code would look something like this:

```
public static void generic_direct(String s)
{
System.out.println("YOU SUBMIT STRING: premium class");
}

public static void generic_direct(Object t)
{
System.out.println("YOU SUBMIT GENERIC: second class");
}
public static void generic_indirect(Object t)
{
// will resolve it to generic_direct(Object)
generic_direct(t);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know, but the question is not about why, but about how to manage that. Any trick !

Comment: None that I know of. As I see it, you either implement a type specific generic_indirect(String) or enhance generic_indirect(T) to check the instance of the parameter and cast it to the corresponding type (String in this case).